# OSGi bundle remains "installed" without conflicts

Tags: osgi

In an OSGi-environment using Apache Felix file-install, one of the bundles does not work.

At first, the bundle does not appear at all; however I can `install` it manually. It becomes INSTALLED (not RESOLVED as it should):

```
osgi>install file:///path/to/my/bundle.jar
Bundle id is 230

osgi>diag 230
file:///[...]
 No unresolved constraints

osgi>ss <filter>
id    State       Bundle
230   INSTALLED   <bundle-name>
```

I can start the bundle with `start 230`, and everything works (services start). After stopping the bundle with `stop 230`, the bundle is RESOLVED; after `update 230` however the bundle enters state INSTALLED again.

How can I identify the cause why the bundle is not RESOLVED automatically?

Answer (score 3):

This is by design:

- Installing a bundle will leave it in installed.
- When you try to start a bundle, the resolver will first try to resolve it's dependencies, if it succeeds it will transition to resolved and from there to started.
- When you stop a bundle, it will transition back to resolved (no need to un-resolve anything at this point as you might want to start it again).
- When you update a resolved bundle, regardless of the fact if this is really a different version of the bundle or not, it will be seen as "new" and it will go to installed state.

So in short: updating a resolved bundle will leave the new version of it in installed state by design.

Comment: So why are all other bundles automatically resolved? I deploy 6 bundles (in total 6 jars) into that OSGi environment; 4 are "RESOLVED", 2 remain "INSTALLED" (and do not appear initially without manual installing).